# Is there a version of solarized color scheme for notepad++

Tags: windows, colors, notepad++, solarized

I've recently switched my Eclipse to [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colors. I would like to do the same thing for Notepad++.

How can I achieve that ?

**UPDATE 1** The Eclipse configuration I use is [Solarized-like](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1012).

Comment: Will you share your Eclipse configuration

Comment: @Ryan_P Updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Solarized fork for Notepad++ on github: https://github.com/ossreleasefeed/solarized/tree/master/notepad++

Comment: The link in nateify's answer didn't work for me but I found this alternative repository:
https://github.com/walesmd/notepad-plus-plus-solarized